# Sass reusable keyframes with mixins and functions

Tags: sass, css-animations, keyframe, scss-mixins

I have four keyframes that look very similiar. Can I do one mixin or function and use it instead of duplicating my code? Keyframes are something like:

```
@keyframes ComputerLogoOuterSquare {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  12% {
    transform: translate(0.5%, 0.5%);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate(0.5%, 0.5%);
  }

  62% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

I tried mixin but it throws an error:

```
@mixin logoAnimation($name, $value) {
  @keyframes $name {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  12% {
    transform: translate($value, $value);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate($value, $value);
  }

  62% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: What errors it throws can share it

Comment: @Ronak07 it's from linter "code": "css-identifierexpected", it underlines `$name` at `@keyframes $name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use interpolation to use $name like

> @keyframes #{$name}